# Responsive resize with input search box on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following problem: I am using datatables with multi column filtering on top. If you watch the video at this link you can understand the problem:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0k900m3tyxse756/screencast.mov?dl=0

When I resize the browser window, the input search fields are still visible causing an overflow in the table. 
Obviously the datatable ha been initialized via javascript with the responsive option.
Here's the HTML:

```
<section class="content">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="block-header">
        <h2>
            VISUALIZZAZIONE OFFERTE ABITATIVE
            <small>Qui potrai visualizzare e ricercare qualsiasi offerta abitativa.</small>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="body">
                    {$sizeOffers = count($offers)}
                    {if $sizeOffers gt 0}
                        {include file=$smarty.const.DEFAULT_RESOURCES_PATH|cat:'inc/offers.tpl'}
                    {else}
                        <div class="alert alert-warning">
                            Non c'&egrave; nessuna offerta abitativa da visualizzare. Clicca sul pulsante in basso per inserirne una ora.
                        </div>
                    {/if}
                    <hr>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a href="/residentialoffer/add" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect">Aggiugi un'offerta</a>
                        {include file=$smarty.const.DEFAULT_RESOURCES_PATH|cat:'inc/back_button.tpl'}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {include file=$smarty.const.DEFAULT_RESOURCES_PATH|cat:'inc/token_field.tpl'}
</div>
```

As you can see, offers.tpl is an included file and contains:

```
<table id="{$id|default:'offers-table'}" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Azioni</th>
    <th>Identificativo</th>
    {if !isset($from_contact)}
        <th>Offerente</th>
    {/if}
    <th>Affitto/Vendita</th>
    <th>Comune</th>
    <th>Telefono</th>
    <th>Provenienza</th>
    <th>Tipologia</th>
    <th>Prezzo</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Azioni</th>
    <th>Identificativo</th>
    {if !isset($from_contact)}
        <th>Offerente</th>
    {/if}
    <th>Affitto/Vendita</th>
    <th>Comune</th>
    <th>Telefono</th>
    <th>Provenienza</th>
    <th>Tipologia</th>
    <th>Prezzo</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
......
</tbody>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Use media querys. When the specific width is reached for example 900px make a display none for the specific field.

Comment: Thank you for the response @hansTheFranz. Can you provide me an example of such media query? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create responsive tables by wrapping any .table in .table-responsive :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Already tried this one, but input search boxes are still visible when I resize the window...